# Ruby & win23ole : How to close window started using shell.ShellExecute

Tags: ruby, win32ole

I am using the code below to start ror server. Is there a easy way to quit that window without  going through the route of finding the pid and using 'taskkill'? I mean after all i have the handle in 'shell' variable don't I?

```
shell = WIN32OLE.new('Shell.Application')
shell.ShellExecute("run_app_server.bat")
```

With the above code a window running ror server shows up. Now I also want to quit it from within the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a reference to an ole automation [Shell object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but once you use ShellExecute to start a process in it's own window, that process belongs to Windows and I don't believe it's exposed in any way via the shell automation object - so there's no way to use an object reference to terminate it.

Rather than using Taskkill from a shell, though, you could also do the search & kill via automation like you're doing now - maybe adapt or "translate" [this Perl script that does it](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=349033).